# Why are the default formats different here? ( Two different implementations of ISO 8601 )

Tags: postgresql

When storing timestamps in jsonb I realized the format used when putting current_timestamp and now() into a jsonb was different than when I used them directly. What is going on here? Although both are ISO8601 formats, I would prefer that they both use the same formatting. Why is there two different defaults?

> ```
> select version();
> select now();
> select current_timestamp;
> select jsonb_build_object('timestamptz', current_timestamp);
> select jsonb_build_object('timestamptz', now());
> ```
>
> ```
> | version                                                                                                |
> | :----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- |
> | PostgreSQL 12.9 on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (GCC) 8.5.0 20210514 (Red Hat 8.5.0-4), 64-bit |
>
> | now                           |
> | :---------------------------- |
> | 2022-07-14 14:13:42.696612+01 |
>
> | current_timestamp             |
> | :---------------------------- |
> | 2022-07-14 14:13:42.696612+01 |
>
> | jsonb_build_object                                  |
> | :-------------------------------------------------- |
> | {"timestamptz": "2022-07-14T14:13:42.696612+01:00"} |
>
> | jsonb_build_object                                  |
> | :-------------------------------------------------- |
> | {"timestamptz": "2022-07-14T14:13:42.696612+01:00"} |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=095ca0e04b3a3c60a5f95c0aa096fbee)*

Comment: My guess is that the JSON constructor is using ISO8601 that enforces the "T", while the previous implementations didn't follow the standard. IMHO I think the "T" hurts readability, so I prefer the "old standard". Anyway, as a friend said once: "The good thing about standards, is that there are lot of them to choose from".

Comment: Thanks,

Both follow a version of ISO 8601 formats; the format without the 'T' is deprecated. It seems odd to have two implementations in one version of PostgreSQL. One doing it based on a deprecated standard  ISO 8601:2004, and the other (newer) format from ISO 8601-1:2019.

Comment: The SQL standard specifies that the format without T is used for timestamp literals and conversion to string of timestamps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The format of a timestamp literal (and by extension, default conversion of a timestamp to string), is defined in ISO/IEC 9075-2:2016 (SQL:2016) section 5.3 <literal> to have a space as the separator between date and time:

```
<timestamp literal> ::=
  TIMESTAMP <timestamp string>

<timestamp string> ::=
  <quote> <unquoted timestamp string> <quote>

<unquoted timestamp string> ::=
  <unquoted date string> <space> <unquoted time string>
```

Both `<unquoted date string>` and `<unquoted time string>` follow the formats of ISO-8601.

So, for standards compliance, interoperability, and backwards compatibility, this format has to be used in SQL itself.

Likely, when PostgreSQL added JSON, this historical baggage of the SQL standard was left out, and instead ISO-8601 was followed, as this is also used by a lot of other JSON serialization solutions, which resulted in using `T` as the separator.

Comment: Great explanation. TIL

Comment: Thanks, 

That finally explains it all. the first format is for SQL standard, and the second was for compliance to JSON(javascript) standard. So yes, they are different.

Comment: @EldonOlmstead The formal standard on JSON ([ECMA-404](https://www.ecma-international.org/publications-and-standards/standards/ecma-404/)) doesn't say anything about datetime serialization, but a lot of JSON serializers do follow this convention.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel, you are right, the JSON standard doesn't say anything, but I think javascript does here:  [Date.toJSON](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toJSON), which may be relevant.

Answer (score 2):

PostgreSQL encodes dates and timestamps in a special way for JSON. See the comment at the start of `JsonEncodeDateTime` in `src/backend/utils/adt/json.c`:

```
/*
 * Encode 'value' of datetime type 'typid' into JSON string in ISO format using
 * optionally preallocated buffer 'buf'.  Optional 'tzp' determines time-zone
 * offset (in seconds) in which we want to show timestamptz.
 */
```

This seems to be [justified by W3](https://www.w3docs.com/snippets/javascript/the-right-json-date-format.html), but I don't know enough about JSON to know what the authoritative standard is and where to find it.

Comment: I have narrowed down the differences to two different versions of the ISO 8601 standard. The first is from 2004 and the other is from 2019. In the 2019 standard, leaving out the 'T' was forbidden, even though it was allowed in the 2004 standard.

See ISO 8601:2004, and ISO 8601-1:2019.